# Invalid transaction:1010 Invalid: Transaction has a bad signature

Tags: transactions, ethereum, ecdsa, signatures

I have changed my default multisignature to EthereumSignature. But whenever i'm doing any transaction on metamask then it is working fine and whenever i'm manually signing the transaction with a keyring of ethereum then also the transaction is working fine.  when i am using explorer of polkadot js apps it is showing the error of invalid transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps on this tutorial [Access EVM Accounts](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/integrate-with-tools/access-evm-accounts/#connect-to-the-node), you have to Setting -> Developer in PolkadotJS UI and define the account information to create an EVM Account as the tutorial explain.

Check this previous Stackexchange question too: 1010: [Invalid Transaction: Transaction has a bad signature](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/8127/1010-invalid-transaction-transaction-has-a-bad-signature)

Comment: But how i can generate the ethereum types account in the polkadot explorer?